# Is is there any reason for keeping the extension `csv` in the method name `read_csv` in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, naming-conventions

Initially, I used to think that read [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in Pandas used to read only the files end with `.csv`.

Later I realized that this method is used to read text file also.

Is there any reason for keeping the extension `csv` in the method name if the method does not process only `csv` files?

Comment: Well, csv files **are** text files. In fact there is no formal specification of the csv format and many variants, so I guess the name is a mix of having a name everyone will understand/be looking for, and providing a generic method. Last thing, extensions are not significant, you can have a csv file without extension, or with anything ass extension. It will work the same.

Comment: Although this is a valid question to raise, I think this belongs as a ticket on GitHub instead on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

the function name reflects the *format* of the data to read, not the name of the file it is read from, and is hence correctly named. `.read_csv()`, just as its siblings `.read_xml()` and `.read_hdf()` etc., can read from any [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), which is not necessarily backed by an actual file on disk.